# question related to iPhone programming certification

Tags: ios

Dear All,
               I am working for iOS application developement. Now am considering to go for certification in iOS application development. I am thinking about expertrating.com. Please guide me if you know any other certification in iOS development with more market value of the certification. Thanks in advance and have a great life ahead.

Answer (score 9):

The de-facto iOS developer certification is to have one or more non-trivial apps, which you wrote, actually available in Apple's iOS App store.  Interviewing companies have been known to download the apps of candidates to try them out.  Apps that use a good cross-section of iOS technologies help.  Good user reviews for these apps also helps.  No other rating or certification currently seems to have anywhere near as much market value, if any.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this twice.  There is NO EXCUSE, if you purport to be an iOS developer, for you not to have *at least* one App in the App Store.  More impressive than any other credential.